# VBA Recursion and hashes

Tags: vba, recursion

I have a bit of a dilema. I am receiving an array of arrays that contains a string in the first element of an array that denotes a hash {HASH}. I dont know the structure of the array of arrays it can be different based upon the result of different calls. An example of the data is as follows:

```
[ [ "{HASH}", 1000, ["{HASH}", "A", 100], ["{HASH}", "B", 150], ["{HASH}", "C", 200] ], 
  [ "{HASH}", 1001, ["{HASH}", "D", 101], ["{HASH}", "E", 151], ["{HASH}", "F", 201] ]
]
```

The hash should then be as follows:

```
{1000}{A}=100
{1000}{B}=150
{1000}{c}=200
{1001}{D}=101
{1001}{E}=151
{1001}{F}=201
```

I have written the following function to be called recurrsively to output the entries in the arrays this is fine, but I need to put this into a Hash as defined and this is where it is failing, because as it is called recursively the hashes are reset etc:

```
Public Function ProcessObjOrArray(Obj As Variant, key As String, ByRef hashIn, HashCreated As Boolean) As Variant

Dim sKey As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim objRes As Variant

If HashCreated = False Then
    Dim hash
    HashCreated = True
    Set hash = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
End If
If IsArray(Obj) Then
    For i = 0 To UBound(Obj, 1)
        objRes = ProcessObjOrArray(Obj(i), sKey, hash, HashCreated)

        If (objRes = "{HASH}") Then
            i = i + 1
            sKey = Obj(i)
        End If
    Next i
    If key <> "" Then
        Debug.Print "Adding {" + key + "}=AllTheStuff"
        Set hash.Item(key) = hashIn

        Dim a
        a = hash.Item(key)("Enabled")
        Exit Function
    End If
Else
    If key <> "" Then
        Debug.Print "Adding {" + key + "}=" + CStr(Obj)
        hash.Item(key) = Obj
    Else
        ProcessObjOrArray = Obj
    End If
End If
End Function
```

The Object passed in is obviously the array I defined above. If someone has a smart way of doing this it would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to declare `hash` as a global variable (and then check if `hash Is Nothing` to see if it has been created yet). Otherwise it just gets created every time a new instance of the function is entered.

Comment: The problem is its not a single hash it's a hash of Hashes and could be even more complex than that. One global hash would not be sufficient

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue, by using a hash passed in and at the end point, creating a new hash which is a copy of the hash passed in, and then finally reset the hash passed in and set is key and value = to the hash I copied. This successfully creates the Hash of hashes